# Mouse Coordinates using Vector2 in Scene2d

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

Just need a little help. I'm basically new to libGDX. What I'm trying to do is get the coordinates of the a mouse click by using this block of code:

```
  @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        Vector2 coord = stage.screenToStageCoordinates(new Vector2((float)screenX, (float)screenY));
        Actor hitActor = stage.hit(coord.x, coord.y, false);
        return true;
    }
```

This does get the coordinates of the mouse click but my concern is, this might trigger the garbage collector since every click might create a new Vector2 coordinates. Any help? Thanks

Comment: I would not be concerned about the garbage collector. And if you should be then you better put a RSI warning on your game :D. It's usually a bad idea to create new objects each frame, but nobody is going to click each frame by a long shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's only in response to a touch down, no need to worry about it because it is so infrequent. If it's for a touch drag, then maybe on a really low end phone, but probably not. If you're in the middle of a big loop, then you should probably avoid it.

Just create a reusable Vector2 in your class and set it before using it each time.

```
private final Vector2 tmp = new Vector2();

//...

stage.screenToStageCoordinates(tmp.set(screenX, screenY);
Actor hitActor = stage.hit(coord.x, coord.y, false);
```

However, all the above is unnecessary if you are using Scene2D. Put a ClickListener on actors that you want to track.

```
actor.addListener(new ClickListener (){
    public void clicked (InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
        doSomethingWithActor(event.listenerActor);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a `Vector2` field in the class containing this variable, then instead of making the coord vector2 every click, just use the `.set` method of the vector2 field in the class.